# Why does cancelling a bluebird promise in a callback stop setInterval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

```
Promise = require 'bluebird'

cb = ->
  console.log 'callback!'
  p = Promise.resolve(5)
    .cancellable()
    .tap -> p.cancel()

setInterval(cb, 100)
```

The `cb` function only is only called once. Commenting out `.tap -> p.cancel()` allows it to run repeatedly. Adding a `try` block doesn't help. Perhaps this is something obvious, but I did some research and can't find an explanation.

Comment: I just ran a simple test and throwing an exception from within a `setInterval()` callback does not stop the timer so that doesn't appear to be related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that the act of returning the value of `p.cancel()` from the `tap` handler is causing bluebird to go into some sort of infinite loop. You never see the second `'callback!'` because the execution context is stuck in this loop before 100 ms have elapsed.

I'm still far from understanding all the factors at play here (see below), but it looks like this can be fixed by not returning `p.cancel()`:

```
Promise = require 'bluebird'

cb = ->
  console.log 'callback!'
  p = Promise.resolve(5)
    .cancellable()
    .tap -> 
        p.cancel()
        null

setInterval(cb, 100)
```

**Edit:** Ok, after looking at the source and unknotting my brain a few times, I think it boils down to this:

Execution is getting stuck in an infinite loop here, where `.cancel()` tries to climb up the promise chain:

```
while ((parent = promiseToReject._cancellationParent) !== undefined &&
    parent.isCancellable()) {
    promiseToReject = parent;
}
```

The salient points are the following:

- `p.cancel()` returns `p`.
- `.tap()` returns a promise that resolves whenever the promise returned from its handler resolves (if it returns a promise)
- `p` is the promise that `.tap()` returns

In other words, `p` is a promise that will resolve after `p` resolves. It is its own ancestor in the promise chain (at least, I think so).

When `.cancel()` tries to climb up the promise chain to find a cancellable promise, it happens upon this incestuous relationship and starts going in circles forever.

In the end, it's an unfortunate consequence of CoffeeScript's eagerness to turn almost everything into a `return` statement. But I would imagine that there's some way Bluebird could detect loops in promise chains and prevent an infinite loop from happening here.

I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/520#issuecomment-76852113) for this on the bluebird GitHub repository, but as the ensuing discussion reveals, this use of `.cancel()` doesn't really make any sense at all anyway.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the analysis. Actually Bluebird can detect loops. If you return a promise in a circle (`p = Promise(5).then -> p`) it will fire a `TypeError: circular promise resolution chain`. I guess I'll lodge a feature request.

Comment: I see you're one step ahead of me.

Comment: I think your should report this as a bug to Bluebird.

Comment: @Bergi [I have](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/520#issuecomment-76852113). That's what Rhys meant when he said I was one step ahead of him. On the other hand, as the ensuing discussion revealed, this use of `.cancel()` doesn't really make any sense at all.